# Android Push Notification Send to all without Limit & Google account

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi my client is asking that it is possible to Send Push notification in android without google account and free also sending to all not 1,000 per request

I have checked GCM but they have limit

and also what if i made my own server which will send request to server every second will it crash the server ??

Thanks

Comment: You cannot get unlimited storage and bandwidth for free.

Comment: it's true but may be there will be another sol. that's why i asked the  question here i will tell client the same thing hope he will feel comfortable with it..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't mean to advertise, but this works flawless for me:

I use a free service called [Parse](https://parse.com/), its pretty easy to push notifications to android as well as iOS devices. The [tutorial](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart) is pretty easy, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but it's also has limitation of 1 million and i think my client will not be happy
but again thanks for your answer i will ask my client if he is comfertable with this

Comment: I think 1 million is pretty generous and the other subscriptions are decently priced. The level of customization definitely adds a lot to it, its a very simple interface that you can use to push anything to users from anywhere. Hope it works out!

Comment: Also, buying a server and using all that time to set it up could end up costing much more.

Comment: One downside of using any other service than GCM is that they will run extra background service.. by default GCM is always running